# Why Application insights appending Console.logs() also into traces?

Tags: node.js, azure-application-insights

Why Application insights appending Console.logs() also into traces ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

- For configuring application insights on console applications you need to set it manually using an instrumentation key this is the reason why it is not showing in traces.
- Here is some related information about [application insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/console) for console applications.